# Why my NSFetchedResultsController loads all rows?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller, nsfetchrequest

I have a NSFetchedResultsController used to display data in a table view (22117 rows). The fetchBatchSize is set to 20 on the fetchRequest. It works as expected: only 20 rows are fully populated when the table view is loaded. SQL statements:

```
2015-06-12 17:59:55.526 BoulderFinder[2228:1220755] CoreData: sql: SELECT 0, t0.Z_PK FROM ZBOULDER t0 ORDER BY t0.ZNORMALIZEDNAME
2015-06-12 17:59:55.533 BoulderFinder[2228:1220755] CoreData: annotation: sql connection fetch time: 0.0070s
2015-06-12 17:59:55.534 BoulderFinder[2228:1220755] CoreData: annotation: total fetch execution time: 0.0075s for 22117 rows.
2015-06-12 17:59:55.534 BoulderFinder[2228:1220755]

2015-06-12 17:59:55.540 BoulderFinder[2228:1220755] CoreData: sql: SELECT 0, t0.Z_PK, t0.Z_OPT, t0.ZBOULDERDESCRIPTION, t0.ZFIRSTCLIMBERFIRSTNAME, t0.ZFIRSTCLIMBERLASTNAME, t0.ZGRADE, t0.ZIMAGE, t0.ZLATITUDE, t0.ZLONGITUDE, t0.ZNAME, t0.ZNORMALIZEDAREANAME, t0.ZNORMALIZEDCIRCUITNAME, t0.ZNORMALIZEDGRADE, t0.ZNORMALIZEDNAME, t0.ZNUMBERINCIRCUIT, t0.ZAREA, t0.ZCIRCUIT FROM ZBOULDER t0 WHERE  t0.Z_PK IN  (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)  ORDER BY t0.ZNORMALIZEDNAME LIMIT 20
2015-06-12 17:59:55.541 BoulderFinder[2228:1220755] CoreData: annotation: sql connection fetch time: 0.0010s
2015-06-12 17:59:55.541 BoulderFinder[2228:1220755] CoreData: annotation: total fetch execution time: 0.0014s for 20 rows.
```

However, I have another view to display the same entities in a different order (only a few entities filtered through a predicate). I am not using a NSFetchedResultsController in this view. If I load this view, where about 59 objects are loaded in the managedObjectContext, and then re-load the other table view, the NSFetchedResultsController now loads all rows (22117) by batches of 20 rows. Here the SQL statements (only the first ones):

```
2015-06-12 18:00:23.315 BoulderFinder[2228:1220755] CoreData: sql: SELECT 0, t0.Z_PK FROM ZBOULDER t0 ORDER BY t0.ZNORMALIZEDNAME
2015-06-12 18:00:23.322 BoulderFinder[2228:1220755] CoreData: annotation: sql connection fetch time: 0.0067s
2015-06-12 18:00:23.322 BoulderFinder[2228:1220755] CoreData: annotation: total fetch execution time: 0.0070s for 22117 rows.
2015-06-12 18:00:23.323 BoulderFinder[2228:1220755] CoreData: sql: SELECT 0, t0.Z_PK, t0.Z_OPT, t0.ZBOULDERDESCRIPTION, t0.ZFIRSTCLIMBERFIRSTNAME, t0.ZFIRSTCLIMBERLASTNAME, t0.ZGRADE, t0.ZIMAGE, t0.ZLATITUDE, t0.ZLONGITUDE, t0.ZNAME, t0.ZNORMALIZEDAREANAME, t0.ZNORMALIZEDCIRCUITNAME, t0.ZNORMALIZEDGRADE, t0.ZNORMALIZEDNAME, t0.ZNUMBERINCIRCUIT, t0.ZAREA, t0.ZCIRCUIT FROM ZBOULDER t0 WHERE  t0.Z_PK IN  (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)  ORDER BY t0.ZNORMALIZEDNAME LIMIT 79
2015-06-12 18:00:23.324 BoulderFinder[2228:1220755] CoreData: annotation: sql connection fetch time: 0.0009s
2015-06-12 18:00:23.324 BoulderFinder[2228:1220755] CoreData: annotation: total fetch execution time: 0.0013s for 20 rows.
2015-06-12 18:00:23.324 BoulderFinder[2228:1220755] CoreData: sql: SELECT 0, t0.Z_PK, t0.Z_OPT, t0.ZBOULDERDESCRIPTION, t0.ZFIRSTCLIMBERFIRSTNAME, t0.ZFIRSTCLIMBERLASTNAME, t0.ZGRADE, t0.ZIMAGE, t0.ZLATITUDE, t0.ZLONGITUDE, t0.ZNAME, t0.ZNORMALIZEDAREANAME, t0.ZNORMALIZEDCIRCUITNAME, t0.ZNORMALIZEDGRADE, t0.ZNORMALIZEDNAME, t0.ZNUMBERINCIRCUIT, t0.ZAREA, t0.ZCIRCUIT FROM ZBOULDER t0 WHERE  t0.Z_PK IN  (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)  ORDER BY t0.ZNORMALIZEDNAME LIMIT 79
2015-06-12 18:00:23.326 BoulderFinder[2228:1220755] CoreData: annotation: sql connection fetch time: 0.0012s
2015-06-12 18:00:23.326 BoulderFinder[2228:1220755] CoreData: annotation: total fetch execution time: 0.0015s for 20 rows.
    ...
```

The only workaround I have found is to call resetContext before setting up the NSFetchedResultsController.

Below the relevant code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:[BDBBoulder entityName]];
    NSSortDescriptor *normalizedNameSortDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"normalizedName" ascending:YES];
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = @[normalizedNameSortDescriptor];
    fetchRequest.fetchBatchSize = 20;
    // [self.fetchedResultsController.managedObjectContext reset];
    self.fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:self.boulderSearch.managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:nil];
    self.fetchedResultsController.delegate = nil;
    // Perform fetch
    NSError *error = nil;
    [self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error];
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"Unable to perform fetch.");
        NSLog(@"%@, %@", error, error.localizedDescription);
    }
}

- (void)configureCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    BDBBoulder *boulder = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.textLabel.text  = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ / %@", boulder.normalizedName,boulder.grade];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ / %@", boulder.normalizedCircuitName,boulder.normalizedAreaName];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    NSArray *sections = [self.fetchedResultsController sections];
    id<NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [sections objectAtIndex:section];

    return [sectionInfo numberOfObjects];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"allBouldersCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    [self configureCell:cell atIndexPath:indexPath];
    return cell;
}
```

I cannot understand this behavior.

---

EDIT:
[image: storyboard]

Comment: Can you give further details of the two view controllers and how you load/reload them.

Comment: I have got a navigation controller embedding a "main view" controller, which is a static table view. From this view, I choose, by clicking the corresponding cell, the view controller to be loaded ("all boulders" view or "around me" view). I am using a storyboard and "show" segues to load the view controllers.

Comment: Thanks.  So the AllBoulders VC is the one with FRC and 22117 rows, and AroundMe is the one with the fetch of about 59 items?  Are they initialised each time you access them?

Comment: Yes you are right. And yes they are initialized each time I access them (the view controllers are instanciated indirectly as specified in the story board).

Comment: Sorry for so many questions.  I have mocked up something similar and can't reproduce the problem.  Have you tried setting `fetchRequest.includesPendingChanges = false`?

Comment: Thanks a lot for the support. I will try it and give my feedback.

Comment: I have no access to my computer right now :-\. It is an interesting test. I forgot to tell that I modify a transient property of the entities fetched by the second view controller ("around me")...

Comment: Thanks again for the support. I have tested with fetchRequest.includesPendingChanges = NO and it works as expected!!! Only the first 20 rows are loaded in memory. As I am only interested in the data in the store and not in "the pending changes" this is the correct setting. However, I am surprised that Core Data fetches all entities in my case. In the "around me" VC I only fetch a few entities and modify a transient property of these objects....

Comment: Strange indeed.  If you were modifying a field that affected the sort order, I could understand it.  I guess Apple must have their reasons.

Comment: I have the same problem but my sectionNameKeyPath is set to nil

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have performed the test again with a simplified app to be sure of the behavior. I have 2 VCs:
- in the first one, I fetch all objects (22117) with a fetchBatchSize of 20 and access to the first element of the results
- in the second one, I fetch 59 objects and modify their transient property

fetchRequest.includesPendingChanges = YES

If I load the first VC, only the first 20 rows are fully loaded:

```
2015-06-16 23:13:45.520 BoulderFinder[946:271012] CoreData: sql: SELECT 0, t0.Z_PK FROM ZBOULDER t0 
2015-06-16 23:13:45.528 BoulderFinder[946:271012] CoreData: annotation: sql connection fetch time: 0.0074s
2015-06-16 23:13:45.528 BoulderFinder[946:271012] CoreData: annotation: total fetch execution time: 0.0081s for 22117 rows.
CoreData: sql: SELECT 0, t0.Z_PK, t0.Z_OPT, t0.ZBOULDERDESCRIPTION, t0.ZFIRSTCLIMBERFIRSTNAME, t0.ZFIRSTCLIMBERLASTNAME, t0.ZGRADE, t0.ZIMAGE, t0.ZLATITUDE, t0.ZLONGITUDE, t0.ZNAME, t0.ZNORMALIZEDAREANAME, t0.ZNORMALIZEDCIRCUITNAME, t0.ZNORMALIZEDGRADE, t0.ZNORMALIZEDNAME, t0.ZNUMBERINCIRCUIT, t0.ZAREA, t0.ZCIRCUIT FROM ZBOULDER t0 WHERE  t0.Z_PK IN  (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)   LIMIT 20
2015-06-16 23:13:45.532 BoulderFinder[946:271012] CoreData: annotation: sql connection fetch time: 0.0012s
2015-06-16 23:13:45.532 BoulderFinder[946:271012] CoreData: annotation: total fetch execution time: 0.0021s for 20 rows.
```

Now, if I load the second VC and then the first VC, then all rows are loaded by batches of 20.

However, if I conduct the same test without modifying the transient property, then only the first 20 rows are fully loaded.

Finally, if fetchRequest.includesPendingChanges = NO

to ignore the pending changes, then it works as expected in all cases.

Strange but this is how it works.
Thank [pbasdf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3985749/pbasdf/).